# Как сделать считывание hex из файла в unsigned char (си)

Tags: c, файлы, char

С обычным char всё просто, а тут возникают проблемы. И ещё можно как-то записать в массив unsigned char константу? то есть к примеру `ch = "ABCD"`.

Comment: `"ABCD"` - это строка, а в тексте вопроса идет речь про "unsigned char константу". Это совсем разные вещи. Так о чем вопрос-то? Что такое вообще `ch = "ABCD"`?

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, в чем проблема-то? Вот массив:

```
unsigned char c[] = "ABCD";
```

Чтение - ну, например, [так](https://ideone.com/XgYJNt):

```
unsigned char b;
in >> noskipws;
while(in >> b) ...
```

Или я просто недопонимаю ваш вопрос? Тогда поясните подробнее, что вам нужно.

В чисто C - [например, так](https://ideone.com/3P6cq2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE * f = fopen(argv[0],"rb");
    unsigned char b;
    while(fread(&b,sizeof(b),1,f)==1)
        printf("%02X",b);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Это си.... тут нет перегрузки операторов и многого другого. fgets не может передать всё в unsigned char.

Comment: А, пардон... не обратил внимания... См. дополненный ответ.